# similar syntax to represent xs:unique in OWL

Tags: owl

Is it possible to express the meaning of xs:unique in OWL?

Say, I define a property `hasID` whose range is integer. 2 different individuals `A` and `B` could not have the same ID. So you don't have `A hasID 1` and `B hasID 1` at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an inverse functional property.  In OWL, there are [inverse functional object properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-syntax-20121211/#Inverse-Functional_Object_Properties), such that if **p** is an inverse functional object property then **p(A,C)** and **p(B,C)** imply **A = B**.
From the specification:

> ### [9.2.8 Inverse-Functional Object Properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-syntax-20121211/#Inverse-Functional_Object_Properties)
>
> An object property inverse functionality axiom
>   InverseFunctionalObjectProperty( OPE ) states that the object property
>   expression OPE is inverse-functional — that is, for each individual x,
>   there can be at most one individual y such that y is connected by OPE
>   with x. Each such axiom can be seen as a syntactic shortcut for the
>   following axiom:
>
> ```
> SubClassOf( owl:Thing ObjectMaxCardinality( 1 ObjectInverseOf( OPE ) ) )
> ```

However, OWL doesn't have inverse functional *datatype properties*.  This is the subject of [What's the problem with inverse-functional datatype properties?](https://web.archive.org/web/20120825001420/http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/12490/whats-the-problem-with-inverse-functional-datatype-properties) on answers.semanticweb.com.  (I'm providing a link to the WaybackMachine's archived version of that page, since the actual site seems to be down.)